# Behavior of falltrough in switch statement

Tags: go, switch-statement

I was reading a section of [this book](http://golangtutorials.blogspot.de/2011/06/control-structures-go-switch-case.html) about the switch statement in Go. But this example confused me:

```golang
 package main

 import "fmt"

 func main() {
 k := 6
 switch k {
    case 4: fmt.Println("was <= 4"); fallthrough;
    case 5: fmt.Println("was <= 5"); fallthrough;
    case 6: fmt.Println("was <= 6"); fallthrough;
    case 7: fmt.Println("was <= 7"); fallthrough;
    case 8: fmt.Println("was <= 8"); fallthrough;
    default: fmt.Println("default case") 
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
was <= 6
was <= 7
was <= 8
default case
```

And the book points out:

> use the fallthrough statement to indicate that the case block following the current one has to be executed.

Now I've to questions:

1. Why does Go compare by default, in which case k is lower?
2. The text mentions that the following cases are executed. Fine. But why aren't they only executed of the case matches k?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Switch statements](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements)
>
> Expression switches
>
> In an expression switch, the switch expression is evaluated and the
>   case expressions, which need not be constants, are evaluated
>   left-to-right and top-to-bottom; the first one that equals the switch
>   expression triggers execution of the statements of the associated
>   case; the other cases are skipped. If no case matches and there is a
>   "default" case, its statements are executed. There can be at most one
>   default case and it may appear anywhere in the "switch" statement. A
>   missing switch expression is equivalent to the boolean value true.
>
> ```
> ExprSwitchStmt = "switch" [ SimpleStmt ";" ] [ Expression ] "{" { ExprCaseClause } "}" .
> ExprCaseClause = ExprSwitchCase ":" StatementList .
> ExprSwitchCase = "case" ExpressionList | "default" .
> ```
>
> In a case or default clause, the last non-empty statement may be a
>   (possibly labeled) "fallthrough" statement to indicate that control
>   should flow from the end of this clause to the first statement of the
>   next clause. Otherwise control flows to the end of the "switch"
>   statement. A "fallthrough" statement may appear as the last statement
>   of all but the last clause of an expression switch.
>
> The expression may be preceded by a simple statement, which executes
>   before the expression is evaluated.

Evaluate case expressions top-to-bottom. `case 4` and `case 5` are `false`, `case 6` is `true`. `case 7`, `case 8`, and `default` are `false` but execute by flowing to the next clause via `fallthrough`.

Comment: Thanks for the quote. Then I understood `fallthrough` firstly wrong. In [this](https://play.golang.org/p/aZg0Qv8Ull) code example I created a simple scenario were each person should guess the integer. Both Alice and Dan are right. Without `fallthrough` the script only prints Alice as the winner and Bob's case isn't checked. I expected, that `fallthrough` searches for other matches and only executes those instead of all. Is there a way to find more than one match in a switch statement without using a for loop?

Comment: @user3147268: No. However, a `switch` statement is special, limited form of `if` statements. Use `if` statements, for example, https://play.golang.org/p/l7NIEdP_Ic

Comment: Ironically is that the reason, why programmers use switch, in order to avoid the if-else clutter.